# SQLite get ids and names WHERE name LIKE

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-like

```
id|  name   |...
--------------
1 |Emmi blaa|..

2 |Emmi haa |..

3 |Emmi naa |..
```

I have SQLite database with table named contacts that contain id, name and other information. I'm trying to get name and id with name variable that I give in EditText.

```
String query = "SELECT name, id FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE \"%" + name + "%\"";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursorC = db.rawQuery(query, null);
while (cursorC.moveToNext()) {
   System.out.println(cursorC.getString(0));
}
```

With the code above, I'm only able to get the names, but not the id so I tried `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
String query = "SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE \"%" + name + "%\" GROUP BY id";
```

Now I get the ids only. How would I get both Id and name with name variable being "mm" for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your issue is not that the first query was not getting the id, rather that you weren't retrieving the id column from the cursor.

The following would work :-

```
String query = "SELECT name, id FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE \"%" + name + "%\"";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursorC = db.rawQuery(query, null);
while (cursorC.moveToNext()) {
   System.out.println(cursorC.getString(0) + " : " + cursorC.getString(1));
}
```

However, ideally you should use the Cursor **getLong** method for retrieving id's as the **id** can be as large as a 64bit signed integer. So  `System.out.println(cursorC.getString(0) + " : " + String.valueOf(cursorC.getLong(1)));` would be better.

Additionally an improvement would be to use the Cursor's **getColumnIndex(the_column_name)** method. This is more flexible as the index of the column is determined according to the column's name. As such `System.out.println(cursorC.getString(cursorC.getColumnIndex("name")) + " : " + String.valueOf(cursorC.getLong(cursorC.getColumnIndex("id"))));` would be recommended (it is also recommended that table and column names are defined as constants and then that those constants are used rather than hard coding the column/table names).

- *e.g. if the query were changed to `SELECT id, name FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE \"%" + name + "%\""` then using hard-coded offsets 0 and 1 would transpose the results. However the results would be unchanged if using getColumnIndex.*
- If you wanted to use the 2nd query `String query = "SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE \"%" + name + "%\" GROUP BY id";` then note that the column names in the Cursor are **id** and **GROUP_CONCAT(name)**, generally an alias would be given to the name using the **AS** keyword. e.g. `String query = "SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS all_names FROM contacts WHERE name LIKE \"%" + name + "%\" GROUP BY id";` The column name in the resultant cursor would then be **all_names**.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is ok with your first query. You are getting only name because you are getting only first column of the result: `System.out.println(cursorC.getString(0));`

To get other columns use similar methods `cursor.getString()` or `cursor.getInteger()` with `1` as parameter. Or even `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))`

From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#ReadDbRow):

> For each row, you can read a column's value by calling one of the Cursor get methods, such as getString() or getLong(). For each of the get methods, you must pass the index position of the column you desire, which you can get by calling getColumnIndex() or getColumnIndexOrThrow().